# Different behavior when connected to laptop

Tags: android, battery

I wrote an application that logs data coming from my smartphone's sensors.
I have a thread that writes this data to a file every hour.
When hooked to my laptop, the app works fine. Every hour a new file is created.

But when the smartphone is disconnected from a laptop it doesn't do that. It doesn't crash but the app ran the whole night and only one file was created...

My code uses Thread.sleep() is this an issue?

I am testing this an a Nexus 5 with android 4.4.4

```
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        String filename = "";
        String directory = "";
        Date now = new Date();

        while (!stopped)
        {
            Log.i(TAG, "Start the one hour sleep");
            sleepForOneHour(now);
            now = new Date();

            directory = directoryDateFormat.format(now);
            filename = filenameDateFormat.format(now);

            Log.i(TAG, "Write data to SD-card");
            setFileWriteDirectory(directory);
            writeDataToSdCard(filename);
        }
        super.run();
    }

    private void sleepForOneHour(Date filesWritten)
    {
        Date now = new Date();
        long nowMillies = now.getTime();
        long filesWrittenMillies = filesWritten.getTime();

        long passedMillies = (nowMillies - filesWrittenMillies);

        long milliesPerHour = (60 * 60 * 1000);

        long waitMillies = (milliesPerHour - passedMillies);

        try
        {
            sleep(waitMillies);
        } catch (InterruptedException e)
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "Interrupted sleep in filehandler thread");
        }
    }
```

**UPDATE**

I tried using `Android.Timer` instead of `Thread.sleep` but this gave the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the phone is not connected to a laptop, it seems that some threads are not executed anymore. Timers and sleeping threads are apparently one of them.

The solution that work for me is to use a WAKE_LOCK. This does seriously affect the power consumption...

In the `onCreate` of my main Activity I acquire a WAKE_LOCK like this.

```
private static WakeLock lockStatic;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    PowerManager mgr = (PowerManager) this.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    lockStatic = mgr.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, TAG);
    lockStatic.setReferenceCounted(true);
    lockStatic.acquire();
    ...
}
```

I release the wakelock in the `onDestroy`. This is not recommended because this will cause the battery to drain a lot faster, but I use the phone as a dedicated logging device, so I don't care that much about the battery life.

```
@SuppressLint("Wakelock")
@Override
protected void onDestroy()
{
    ...
    lockStatic.release();
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few educated guesses and suggestions.

1. A smart phone has some very stringent power-down-while-not-used functionality. Some of this functionality will shutdown interrupts that are not "vital".
2. Check the clock your sleep call uses. The basis of some timers is clock ticks, and when in a low power state, clock ticks also slow down and sometimes stop.
3. Check to see if there is some special threading call you need to keep a thread operating (including waking up from a sleep) while the phone is in a low power state.

Regards